# How to make .focus() work on a radio button array?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to get the .focus() working in IE, it works in chrome etc.  My form is called:

```
<form name="feedbackform" action="feedback.asp" target="_self" onsubmit="return 
        validate_txt(this)" method="post" style="margin: 0;">
```

my radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Comment" />Comment
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Complaint" />Complaint
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Request" />Request
```

in my javascript I am trying to call using this line:

```
document.forms["feedbackform"].elements["fb_commentype"][0].focus();
```

As I said, it works in chrome, firefox blah blah blah but in IE 8 I am getting nada, zip and I don't know why, nor can I find a satisfactory answer, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling focus when the page just loads (e.g. body's onload)?

[This thread might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8) - it may get called in your code before DOM finished loading

Also, this page has a good test for focus() behavior:
http://hardlikesoftware.com/projects/IE8FocusTest.html

Comment: No, its a check function when the user presses the submit button, validates input and if something is missing sets the focus to that item.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Comment" />Comment
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Complaint" />Complaint
<input type="radio" name="fb_commentype" value="Request" />Request
```

Simple, look at your radio button as an array, you can focus any radio button of the array by pointing to the right index, see below.

```
document.getElementsByName('fb_commentype')[0].focus();
```

that way the "Comment" radio button will be focused...

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be that IE does not understand the .[0].focus() syntax. You may want to try something like this:

```
document.forms["feedbackform"].elements["fb_commentype"][0].focus();
document.forms["feedbackform"].elements["fb_commentype"].focus();
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the comment, I will test this and let you know what happens.