# JQuery focus() is not focusing in IE but it is in Chrome

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#reporter').blur(function() {
            if(data.indexOf('['+jQuery('#reporter').val()+']') >= 0)
            {
                alert("Please do not select pseudo user as Reporter");
                jQuery('#reporter').focus();                    
            }               
        });
```

In IE, the cursor is not blinking in the "reporter" element. In Chrome, it is.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are we to assume reporter is a `<input type=text` or a `textarea`?

Comment: Not the problem, but: Note that *every time* you call `jQuery('#reporter')` jQuery has to go off and do that. Within the `blur` handler, you could do `var $this = $(this);` at the top and then use `$this` rather than `jQuery('#reporter')`, saving a bit of trouble and verbosity.

Comment: this has been answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to set the blur later by using a timeout. The other control might execute focus first.

### Suggestion

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   $('#reporter').focus();
}, 50);
```

This gives IE the time to focus the other control, steal the focus and then add it to `#reporter`.

### Prevent action

```
$('#reporter').blur(function(e) {
    if(data.indexOf('[' + jQuery('#reporter').val() + ']') >= 0) {
        alert("Please do not select pseudo user as Reporter");
        $('#reporter').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I do the setTimeout() thing and it behaves