# JQuery focus() not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

In My Application i m using RichTextEditor on a form with some other fields. I set focus on first text box like this

```
$("#tofield").focus();
```

But as RichTextBox is taking some time to load, so when RichTextBox loading complete focus 
removed from first text box.

I searched on it and found some suggestions to use setTimeout

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tofield").focus();
    }, 1000);
```

but it is also not working

focus() is only working in FF not in Chrome and IE

Any suggestions..

Comment: Can't you use some kind of a load callback function? What happens when you set the timeout to 10000?

Comment: @Shomz with setTimeout as well focus just removed from textbox...,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996577/jquery-focus-is-not-focusing-in-ie-but-it-is-in-chrome

Comment: just check whether you having two fields with same id, this is some common error often occur

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8mpRg/1/

Comment: @PandiyanCool , thanks for you reply, but your HTML don't have any Text Editor, focus is loosing because Editor is taking time to load..

Comment: @Suganthan , i double check there is only one field with id tofield

Comment: @Anil D then try with $( window ).load() function and debug, as because your resources are taking time to load please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready

Comment: @AnilD I just tried to give you some sample:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to share how i fixed this...

Not sure how and why it is working but it did the trick

I just added following line of code before TextBox

```
<input type="button" id="btntofieldfocus" style="width:0px;height:0px !important;padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;position:absolute;left:-50px;" value="" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('tofield').focus()" />
```

May help others...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('#tofield').focusout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking time to load you can try with this

```
        $( window ).load(function() {
            $("#tofield").focus();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#tofield").focus();
});
```