# Cannot set focus on a textbox in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

IE8 seems to be the bane of my existence lately. I am trying to set focus when a new step is created in my application. Here is my code:

```
$(this).stepField('action_description').focus();
```

This works in all other browsers I've tested with (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). It even works in IE9, but not IE8. Any help would be vastly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `stepField` ? Is that a plugin ? What does it return in IE8 ?

Comment: yea can you tell us what stepField is doing? does it work witout stepField?

Comment: stepField is merely a function to return the name of the step:
    `stepField: function(name) {
      return this.step().find(':input[name="step[' + name + ']"]');
    },`

Answer (score 1):

To work in ie8 :

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myElement').focus();
    }, 10);
```

---

SO source:  [jQuery focus() sometimes not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8)

Issue documented by MS : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954

Comment: I don't have technical details, but I have seen documentation that says this method allows IE/Windows to sequence statement execution correctly. Some more details : http://javascript.gakaa.com/div-focus-4-0-5-.aspx

Comment: leave the source where you took the other SO answer from

Comment: @Jason Bodak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: No problem. Also, here is the issue documented by MS http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954

Comment: but that's setting focus on the window, I don't think that's the case here

Comment: I tried Nicholmikey's solution, but alas, it did not fix the problem.