# Keep cursor in html input when moving the input across DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

is there any simple way to keep cursor in an input element when I move the element across DOM?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y1nu1q4f/1/

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='a' /> ho ho ho
    <input type='text' name='b' /> merry christmas
</form>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    $('input[name="a"]').appendTo($('form'));
    $('input[name="b"]').appendTo($('form'));
}, 3000);
</script>
```

This example moves the text input after 3 seconds. When the input is focused (cursor is inside), it loses focus when moved. Is it possible to keep/return the cursor to its original position?

In my app I have many inputs in a form which's DOM is being reorganized like this, so I need some simple and flexible solution, not putting bunch of extra attributes and code for each input. jQuery solution is preferred to pure javascript.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mq4grbmw/

Comment: Sorry, this won't help as I commented the answer below. I tried to update the example to be more clear - I have more inputs and I need to keep the focus in the input it was before, not just focus single input after moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var focusedElement = jQuery(':focus'); // ideally specify tag, class or ID here before the ':focus' to avoid jQuery scanning all elements on the page.

    $('input[name="a"]').appendTo($('form'));
    $('input[name="b"]').appendTo($('form'));

    if (focusedElement && focusedElement.length) { //fixed var name here
        focusedElement.focus();
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost it. However, MSIE (tested in 11) focuses the element, however does not place cursor in it (and I can only dream about placing the cursor to its original position in IE), which is done in other browsers automatically even to the original position.  Is there a suitable solution for MSIE at least 9,10 and 11?

Comment: I'm not sure but this SO item may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: thanks, this helped: setTimeout(function(){ focusedElement.focus(); }, 10);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `focus()` to focus on an element.

If I take your jsfiddle as example you just add `$('input').focus();` in your function after the switch. And you're good to go.

So:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('input').appendTo($('form'));
   $('input').focus();
}, 3000};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mq4grbmw/)

Comment: Thanks, but 1) I don't know if the input was focused before the move - your script will focus it always after moving DOM - this is not intended, I want to keep focus where it was before reorganizing DOM. 2) as I said, I have many inputs on my website, so I must determine where the focus was before the move, not just focus any particular input. So, this won't help.